# Extract ROI From Image with a Skew Angle OpenCv Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have been using the

```
 x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingBox(cnt)
 roi = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

function in openCv in order to get a portion of the image within a contour.
However, I am now trying to use the openCv function minAreaRect in order to get my bounding box. The function returns the x and y coordinates of each corner, along with the skew angle. Example:

```
 ((363.5, 676.0000610351562), (24.349538803100586, 34.46882629394531), -18.434947967529297)
```

Is there a simple way of extracting this portion of the image? Because I can obviously not do

```
 roi = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

Because of the skew angle and such. I was going to possibly rotate the entire image and extract the points, but this would take far too long when going through thousands of contours at once.
What I currently get is encompassed within the green rectangle, and what I want is in the red rectangle. I want to extract this portion of the image, but cannot figure out how to select a diagonal rectangle.

[image]

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? You can create a mask of any shape use that to isolate what you want.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I select the mask within the image if I have the rectangle and its skew angle? I am looking for an output that represents the portion of a larger image represented by the output of minAreaRect. I am not sure how to find this output, however, when a skew angle is included within the points. @HåkenLid

Comment: You create a black image with the same dimensions as the image, then you draw a the rotated rectangle in white. That's your mask. You can use it as an alpha channel.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your explanation of the output you want. Can you include an example image in the question?

Comment: Just added. @HåkenLid

Comment: Can you attach expected output along with the question ?

Comment: I really start understanding while questions are downvoted and / or not answered. To answer the question one has to find appropriate image, guess expected result, write minimum relevant code to start with and then find the answer. It would be nice, if you perform all steps, but the last one.

Comment: The answer to your question in C++: http://answers.opencv.org/question/497/extract-a-rotatedrect-area/